# App Crashed when clicked to open the Activity of graph

Tags: android, charts

I'm doing a creating a piechart in this activity.
Everything works fine until I click the ListView that intent to my Chart Activity.
And the whole application just crashed.
Is there something wrong with the codes?

This is my Chart1.class

```
    package com.nyp.exploregowhere;

     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.util.AttributeSet;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
     import android.webkit.WebSettings;
     import android.webkit.WebView;

       public class Chart1 extends Activity {

         @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart1);
}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.chartView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/explore.html");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(getApplicationContext(), "ExploreDB");

    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chart1, menu);
      return true;
  }

}
```

07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2966)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3029)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:286)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.nyp.exploregowhere.Chart1.onCreate(Chart1.java:18)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-03 10:42:56.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)

Please help !

Comment: That is not a complete stack trace. Not only do you need to look at the whole stack trace, but you need to look at line 18 of `Chart.java`, which would appear to be the source of your difficulty.

Comment: what do you mean by a whole stack trace?

Comment: I mean what I said -- that is not a complete stack trace. There is no statement of what the exception is, for example, so you are missing 1+ lines at the top.